# A parabola touches a conic at two points where the conic is intersected by a line

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I need to find the equation of a parabola which touches the conic $x^2+y^2+xy-2x-2y+1=0$ at the points where it is intersected by the line $x+y+1=0$

My book says that since the parabola $(P)$ touches the conic $S=0$ $(S \equiv x^2+y^2+xy-2x-2y+1)$ at the points where it is intersected by the line $L= 0$ $(L \equiv x+y+1)$, then the parabola is in double contact with the conic at these points. So they took the equation of the parabola as

$\phi \equiv S+\lambda L^2=0$

Where does this come from? How is this true? Does it come from the fact that there are two points of intersection of the conic and the line???

Also, I graphed out the conic and the line, and from there I saw that the conic doesn't really touch the ellipse. Is the question wrong or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Your line doesn't intersect the ellipse over the reals. Using $x+y-1=0$ which does instead: $x^2+y^2+xy-2x-2y+1+\lambda(x+y-1)^2$

The quadratic part is then $(\lambda+1)y^2+(2\lambda+1)xy+(\lambda+1)x^2$ from which

$B^2-4AC=(2\lambda+1)^2-4(\lambda+1)^2=-4l-3$ and we get a parabola for $\lambda=-\frac34.$ See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVPjT.png)

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Yes, but how does this form come, that $S+\lambda L2 =0$? It looks like something like a family of conics, but how do I know to use that? Where does that come from ?

Comment: You do get a pencil, but there's a parabola in there for $\lambda=-\frac34$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Pencil? What do you mean?

Comment: A one-parameter family of conics is called a [pencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(mathematics)) of conics.

Comment: Could you kindly point to a source/reference where I can get more information about families of conics?

Comment: Also, why am I using $S+\lambda L^2 = 0$ and not $S+\lambda L = 0$ (something which I am used to doing in circles or straight lines). Example: My book says that the equation of the family of circkes passing through the points of intersection of the line $L = 0$ and a circle $S=0$ is given by $S+\lambda L = 0$

Comment: $L^2=0$ is a double line and a degenerate conic. Two conics meet in four points with multiplicity (over ${\Bbb C}$) and in the case above all the points are real; each member of the pencil has two double contacts. The parabola in the pencil is no exception.

Comment: Thanks, I found the required material in the book by SL Loney. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction

Comment: I have to wonder if the imaginary intersection was intentional, or if there’s a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland The gist of the above discussion seems like it ought to be an answer.

Comment: @amd No it isn't intentional, the book's solution acts exactly as if it's real, so it's definitely a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse $S=x^2+y^2+xy-2x-2y+1=0$ doesn't meet the line $x+y+1=0,$ but it does meet $L=x+y-1=0.$ Now the [pencil of conics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system_of_conics) $S+\lambda L^2=0,$ has as members $S=0$ for $\lambda=0$ and the double line $L^2=0,$ for $\lambda = \infty.$ ($\lambda$ is usually thought of as belonging to ${\Bbb P}^1$ and one sees $\mu S+\lambda L^2=0,$ where $\lambda, \mu$ are homogeneous coordinates on ${\Bbb P}^1$ as an alternate form of the same pencil).

Every other member in the pencil will be tangent to $S=0$ at the two points of intersection $S=0\cap L=0.$ The fixed locus of the pencil are the two double points of this intersection.

**Aside** [Enumerative geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerative_geometry) is based on notions like "touching at these two points" being preserved in families. A curve intersecting a double line technically is tangent there; this is why $6^5=7776$ (A naive application of Bezout's theorem on the fact that the condition to be tangent to a conic is of degree 6) is the wrong answer to the question "How many conics are tangent to 5 given conics," the double lines in some precise sense contributes the difference to the actual number 3264.

The problem to find the parabola $P$ in this family can be solved by looking for the $\lambda$ for which $S+\lambda L^2=0$ has a quadratic term that is a square of linear terms, this is what the discriminant gives us: $B^2-4AC=(2\lambda+1)^2-4(\lambda+1)^2=0,$ which gives $\lambda=-\frac34,$ or $P=\frac14(x^2-2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1)=0$ or $P=\frac14((x-y)^2-2x-2y+1)=0.$